# C++ using compare - Left of '.compare' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, nodes

I'm trying to create a program that reads through an array of nodes to see if one with a duplicate name is about to be created.

Currently I'm getting the error C2228: left of '.compare' must have class/struct/union

I think the fact that getName() returns a pointer to a char array could have something to do with this but I really don't know what to do.

Node.h simply includes constructors for Node.

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
#include "istream"
#include "new"
#include "Node.cpp"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //name of file to be opened
    char filename[]="resource.txt";

    //temporary holding place of strings
    char temp[256];


    //Node Array
    Node<char [256]> * resourceArray;
    resourceArray = new Node<char [256]>[1];
    int resourceArraySize=1;
    Node<char [256]> * tempNode;

    std::ifstream reFile;
    //File is opened
    reFile.open(filename, std::ifstream::in);


    if(reFile.is_open())
    {

        while(!reFile.eof()){
            //get the first item on a line and store it in temp
            if(reFile.getline(temp,256,' ')){
                //
                for(int i=0;i<=resourceArraySize;i++){
                    //if index is greater that array size, reallocate array
                    if(i>=resourceArraySize){
                        tempNode = new Node<char [256]>[2*resourceArraySize];
                        std::copy(resourceArray,resourceArray+resourceArraySize,tempNode);
                        delete resourceArray;
                        resourceArray = tempNode;
                        delete tempNode;
                        resourceArraySize = resourceArraySize * 2;
                     }

                    if(resourceArray[i].getName.compare(temp)){

                    }
                }
            }
            if(reFile.getline(temp,256,'\n')){
                //TODO:Create a node, if necessary and add to previous's nodes requires array.
            }
        }

        //File is closed
        reFile.close();
    }else{
        perror("Error opening file\n");
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"

//Default Constructor
template<class T>
Node<T>::Node(){

}

//This constructor sets the next pointer of a node and the data contained in  that node
template<class T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& item,Node<T>* ptrnext){
    this->data = item;
    this->next = ptrnext;
    useable=true;
    requiresSize=1;
}

//This method inserts a node after the current node
template<class T>
void Node<T>::insertAfter(Node<T> *p){
    //Links the rest of list to the Node<T>* p
    p->next = this->next;

    //Links the previous node to this one
    this-> next = p;
}

//This method deletes the current node from the list then returns it.
template<class T>
Node<T> * Node<T>::deleteAfter(){

    Node<T>* temp = next;

    if(next !=NULL){
        next = next->next;
    }

    return temp;
}

template<class T>
Node<T> * Node<T>::getNode(const T& item, Node<T>* nextptr = NULL){
    Node<T>* newnode; //Local pointer for new node
    newNode = new Node<T>(item,nextptr);
    if (newNode == NULL){
        printf("Error Allocating Memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    return newNode;

}

template<class T>
void Node<T>::setName(char input[]){
    strncpy(name,input,sizeof(name));
}

template<class T>
char * Node<T>::getName(){
    return name;
}

template<class T>
bool Node<T>::isUseable(){
    return useable;
}

template<class T>
void Node<T>::setUseable(bool use){
    useable = use;
}

template<class T>
void Node<T>::addRequirement(char item[256]){
    int i=0,end=0;
    char * temp;

    while(end==0){
        //if search index is larger than size of the array,reallocate the array
        if(i>= requiresSize){
            temp = new char [requiresSize*2][256];
            std::copy(requires,requires + requiresSize,temp);
            delete requires;
            requires = temp;
            delete temp;
            requiresSize = requiresSize *2;         
        }
        //if the index at requires is not empty, check to see if it is the same as given item
        if(requires[i]!= NULL){
            if(item.compare(requires[i])){
                //if they are the same, break out of the loop, item is already included
                break;
            }else{
                //otherwise, increase the index and check again (continue loop)
                i++;
            }
        }else{
            //if the index is empty, add the item to the list and break out of loop
            requires[i]=item;
            end=1;
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getName` is a method.

change `if(resourceArray[i].getName.compare(temp)){` to `if(strcmp(resourceArray[i].getName(), temp) == 0){`

Comment: @Chaospyke getName() returns `char *` not `std::string`. And you cannot call a function on a pointer.  If you want to use compare(),, you can return std::string from getName().

Answer (score 0):

getName is, more accurately, a method that returns a pointer, and resourceArray is also a pointer. Try:
if(resourceArray[i]->getName->compare(temp))